# Ant com JUnitParams

Tags: junit, selenium-webdriver, jenkins

Gente, estou utilizando o ANT junto com o Jenkins para fazer a Integração contínua certo? Utilizo o ANT inicialmente para a execução dos testes automatizados e depois gero a build da aplicação. Meu problema se resume na execução dos testes automatizados com o ANT. A maioria dos meus testes são parametrizados (leio a massa de dados de um CSV e dou o input no campo), porém quando mando executar o `build.xml` do ANT para a execução dos testes, ele apenas consegue executar os testes que não são parametrizados. O erro que ocorre é devido a ele não conseguir ler o CSV, parece a falta da biblioteca do JUnitParams, porém já conferi inúmeras vezes e ela está na pasta lib (de onde o ant puxa as libs necessárias). Segue o StackTrace do erro que ocorre:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not successfully read parameters from file: classpath:UC003_editarIdentificacao/UC003-Massa_de_dados_Identificacao.csv
    at junitparams.internal.TestMethod.paramsFromFile(TestMethod.java:141)
    at junitparams.internal.TestMethod.parametersSets(TestMethod.java:124)
    at junitparams.internal.TestMethod.isIgnored(TestMethod.java:81)
    at junitparams.internal.TestMethod.isNotIgnored(TestMethod.java:88)
    at junitparams.internal.ParameterisedTestClassRunner.addTestMethodForEachParamSet(ParameterisedTestClassRunner.java:82)
    at junitparams.internal.ParameterisedTestClassRunner.computeFrameworkMethods(ParameterisedTestClassRunner.java:56)
    at junitparams.internal.ParameterisedTestClassRunner.<init>(ParameterisedTestClassRunner.java:32)
    at junitparams.JUnitParamsRunner.<init>(JUnitParamsRunner.java:390)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.Reader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at junitparams.internal.TestMethod.createProperReader(TestMethod.java:155)
    at junitparams.internal.TestMethod.paramsFromFile(TestMethod.java:132)
```

Comment: Achou alguma solução? Poste como resposta para ajudar outras pessoas.

Comment: @Thiago Zluhan de Medeiro achou alguma solução?